# Is there a version of the Hoya bella that doesn't climb, or hang?

Tags: identification, flowers, succulents

My mother in law swears she had a miniature Hoya carnosa with tiny leaves with white flowers that had a red center all over it, which she has pointed out on the Hoya carnosa but said that hers didn't have anything hanging down and the leaves on hers were tiny. This was over 40 years ago and I was thinking that maybe it was a plant that looks similar to a Hoya carnosa with the same flowers? If anyone could please help me out with this question I would greatly appreciate your time and help, and if by some chance you do know what she is talking about and you know where I could get one for her, well you would be my best friend and make my decade. Thank everyone who read this for your time!

Comment: There are over 500 species of Hoya - most trail or vine, but some don't.As to which one your mother in law means, its not one I know, but there's  a list of all the varieties towards the end in this link https://plantcaretoday.com/hoya-plant-care.html Not sure  how useful it will be though, and maybe someone else knows exactly the plant you mean

Comment: Welcome Late2soon! Thanks so much for joining us! I don't actually know anything about Hoyas, so I'm not the right one to answer your question, but we do have a lot of plant experts, so I hope someone can help you! While you're waiting, I invite you to take our [tour] and look around the pages of our [help]. [Ask] and [Answer] are good places to start. We're different from other sites you might be used to, so in case you have any questions about our system, just let us know!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help! I will check out the link and see if I can find what she is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

There are bush types of Hoya; try searching for "Hoya bella". You will find it is a green leaf type as opposed to the variegated, but varieties do have red in the flower. Hoya bella makes a basket type plant, so while sort of vining the internodes are shorter than the Hoya carnosa and other vining types and so much more compact and under control. A useful search term is "short internodes".

Comment: Thank you so much! You wouldn't know where I could purchase one of these? I can't seem to find one at any local nursery.

Comment: A Google search on "Hoya bella" came up with at least two sites that offered to sell me one online and ship it to me. I guess it depends on where on the globe you are located, but an online retailer should be easy to find by adding the country into the search bar.